# Understanding RFC6265 domain-matching conditions

Tags: cookies, domain-name, rfc6265

I'm looking to implement a straightforward method to check if a given cookie domain domain-matches a given hostname.

To do this I will be implementing the domain matching conditions defined in [section 5.1.3 of RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3).

The second of the two matching conditions defined is a multipart condition where three sub-conditions apply:

> All of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The domain string is a suffix of the string.
> - The last character of the string that is not included in the domain string is a %x2E (".") character.
> - The string is a host name (i.e., not an IP address).

For clarity, when the above quoted text refers to "the string" it is referring to the domain value of a cookie and when the above quoted text refers to "the domain name" it is referring to the domain name of a host to which cookies might be sent.

Of these three sub-conditions, the first and third are quite clear. It is the wording of the second that I am finding confusing.

I do know that a cookie domain of "example.com" matches only "example.com" and a cookie domain of ".example.com" matches "<anything>.example.com". My best guess is that above second sub-condition if referring to this broad subdomain matching concept, however given the wording I can't be sure.

Is anyone able to translate this second sub-condition into plain technical English?

Answer (score 1):

I have also struggled a lot when trying to understand that particular condition.  After the fifteenth read I noticed that I wasn't paying attention to the key words.  Quoting (and emphasizing):

> - The last character of the string **THAT IS NOT INCLUDED** in the domain string is a %x2E (".") character.

So I believe the following Python 3 implementation would be compliant to the RFC:

```py
import ipaddress

def domain_matches (string: str, domain_string: str) -> bool:
    string = string.lower()
    domain_string = domain_string.lower()
    try:
        ipaddress.ip_address(string)
        is_host = False
    except ValueError:
        is_host = True
    return (
        string == domain_string
        or
        (string.endswith(domain_string)
         and
         string[-(len(domain_string) + 1)] == "."
         and
         is_host)
    )
```

The `ipaddress` bit is to be fully pedantic.  However, for my use case I omitted it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [section 4.1.2.3 of RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3)

> For example, if the value of the Domain attribute is "example.com", the user agent will include the cookie in the Cookie header when making HTTP requests to example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and [www.corp.example.com](http://www.corp.example.com).  (Note that a leading %x2E ("."), if present, is ignored even though that character is not permitted, but a trailing %x2E ("."), if present, will cause the user agent to ignore the attribute.)

So the logic would be:

```
1. check targetString endsWith domain
2. check lastChar(targetString) != "."
3. check targetString is host name
```